# Oracle 19c installation stuck at creating and starting oracle instance

Tags: oracle-19c

I'm trying to install oracle 19c but it's stuck at 52% for over 7 hours. So cancelled it and uninstalled it. I have started installing again but still stuck at 52% that is in creating and starting oracle instance. [image: installation stuck at 52% for hours]

Answer (score 0):

Two of the most common reasons for the Oracle DB installation to get stuck at this point are:

- inability to write to `%TEMP%` directory (usually as a result of AD domain policies or a full disk)
- virus check software (other than Windows Defender) interfering with the installation process

If you need to cancel the installation and try again, be sure to confirm that the `%TEMP%` directory on your Windows box does not have any leftover directories prefixed with `deinstall`, `OraInstall` or `CVU`, as these may be reused by future installations, creating a different set of issues.

Comment: Thank you. Also is the problem occurring because i am using windows 10 home version cause I've read somewhere that oracle 19c does not support the home version.